# Wedge and common notation for "a line between two points"

Tags: geometry, notation, twistor-theory

I'm using a somewhat old presentation from 2011 that covers twistor geometry.

It uses the notation "$L = Z_1 \wedge Z_2$" to suggest that the line $L$ is the "join of the twistors $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, which are simply points in this twistor space.

However, I have always learned that the line between two points, which is essentially what this is, is just given by writing $L=Z_1Z_2$. Is there any difference between the two? Does this wedge notation have any other meaning that I'm not aware of? Is there any other standard notation that I have omitted?

EDIT:
For reference, the full presentation is available at https://indico.cern.ch/event/137430/contributions/146026/attachments/113502/161251/Atrani_1_Duhr.pdf.

See the screenshot [of the relevant section here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qjhH.png).

EDIT2: Found the answer, will accept in 2 days when I'm allowed to! See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer lies in Boolean algebra. [Why is $\wedge$ a minimum and $\vee$ a maximum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839344/why-is-wedge-a-minimum-and-vee-a-maximum) and http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/BooleanAlg.pdf are the resources used. Turns out that in Boolean notation $A \wedge B = AB$, who'd've thunk'd it!