# notation - what does this $\wedge$ inside the integral mean?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, notation, lebesgue-integral

I have this integral:
$\int(\epsilon \wedge \|x\|^{2})\nu(dx)$

The $\wedge$ symbol means that I have to integrate $\|x\|^{2}$ when $\|x\|>\epsilon$ or when $\|x\|>1$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839344/why-is-wedge-a-minimum-and-vee-a-maximum

Comment: Simply put, it refers to the "minimum", i.e. $a\land b = \min(a,b)$.

Comment: It is a notation borrowed from Lattice theory, occasionally used in some approaches to measure theory: specifically $$\begin{split}\wedge\equiv\text{ "meet"}&\implies a\wedge b=\min(a,b)\\ \vee\equiv\text{ "join"}\,\,&\implies a\vee b=\max(a,b)\end{split}\text{ if }a,b\in\Bbb R.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wedge stands for minimum. $a\wedge b=\min\{a,b\}$. The integral is $\int_{\{\|x||^{2} \geq \epsilon\}} \epsilon \nu (dx)+\int_{\{\|x||^{2} < \epsilon\}} \|x\|^{2} \nu (dx)$.

Comment: It would be perhaps easier to read if you added a line at the beginning to indicate that $\wedge$ means $\min$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Thanks for the comment.