# What does the conjunction symbol ∧ mean with regards to stochastic processes and probability theory

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

I understand that $\land$ denotes a conjunction, but what does this mean when applied to stochastic processes? I have come across part of my Stochastic Calculus notes that features reference to the process:

$$X(t \land \tau_n)_{t \in \left[0, T\right]}$$

where $\tau_n$ is the $n$th in a sequence of stopping times. Does this mean that the process $X$ can only take as input values such that $t = \tau_n$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3139908/notation-what-does-this-wedge-inside-the-integral-mean?noredirect=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the min function. So $a \wedge b = \text{min}(a,b)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was not explained in my notes anywhere so I think I was just assumed to have known this from the get-go.